# Generate a list random numbers eliminating the random numbers in another list in Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to generate list of random numbers that are not there in first list. Keeping the size of the list similar as the first one. I have done it R as below .
Example:

bb <- sample(1:25,10)

bb

[1] 11 19 23 15 25 12 14 21 10  4

wd <- sample((1:25)[-bb],10)

wd

[1] 13  1  5  9 22  3  2 24  7 16

I want the same thing to be replicated in python . I have tried several ways which was useless.

Kindly help .. Thanks in Adavance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us what you have tried and create a [mre].

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this :

```
import random

l1 = [11, 19, 23, 15, 25, 12, 14, 21, 10, 4]
l2 = []

while len(l2) < len(l1):
    while True:
        r = random.randint(1, 25)
        if r not in l1 and r not in l2: 
            l2.append(r)
            break
        
print(l2) #==> [16, 20, 2, 9, 3, 18, 6, 24, 17, 7]
```

Comment: @Patrick Artner : you're right I fixed that. For your second remark, I wasn't aware that the question is off topic, sorry.

Comment: Oups... naturally I forgot that, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you don't have a test list, you could use the **sample** function of the **random** module in python which would give you a unique list of elements in the range that you prefer and the corresponding no. of elements required.

Further which you can use a simple **while loop** and **if condition** to make sure there are no duplicates being inserted into the second list.

The code sample for the same would be like this:

```
import random

n = int(input("Enter the length of the required list: "))

l1=random.sample(range(1,100), n)

l2=[]
while len(l2) < len(l1):
    while True:
        r = round(random.randint(1, 100))
        if r not in l1 and r not in l2: 
            l2.append(r)
            break

print("List 1: ",l1) 
print("List 2: ",l2)
```

You would ideally get two unique lists everytime you run this script.

Sample Output:

```
List 1:  [14, 80, 55, 88, 4, 30, 82, 95, 23, 93]
List 2:  [49, 64, 78, 87, 8, 79, 31, 28, 51, 92]
```